# TFS - Checkout File from Outside Visual Studio - Offline Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i have used TF.exe (Team Foundation Client) to checkout files from outside with the following command.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2007/01/22/real-tfs-command-line-help.aspx

```
tf checkout $project/filename
```

but, i need to checkout from outside when TFS server is also not reachable. In visual studio, it prompts us to work offline and then later on, it sync automatically with the changes into server when it goes online. How do i acheive the same from tf.exe or any other way to do it.

PS: i do have real requirement of editing some files which is not belongs solution files which gets modified from outside of visual studio. as of now,i am using tf checkout method to checkout the file from outside. but, this require connection TFS server all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with the command-line tools, because the offline mode is a feature of Visual Studio, not of TFS.

The tools always work directly with the TFS, so it must be online and reachable at that time.

Amendment regarding your P.S.: What Visual Studio does in Offline mode is just setting the local files to writable and "remembering" with which files it did that. Then, on going online again, it checks for any changes in the meantime. If there were any, it starts a merge process, if there weren't, it checks out the file without getting it.

There's no reason why you couldn't do this same process by hand, it's just more comfortable through VS.

BTW: Why not have a Solution for this "dangling files"? Just create an emtpy solution and add them as Solution Items. This way you can use the VS offline mode.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. The reason i can not add in Empty solution is that, these are all XML files which gets modified outside the visual studio. By keeping it solution is not going to help me since, TFS is making all the files into read only, i have to checkout to make any modification from outside.

Comment: @Jeeva S: It's hard to tell from here without further information, but why can't you check out the files before applying the outside modification? If they are in Source Control, you have to check them out anyway to apply changes, one way or the other.

Comment: see, we have another GUI tool for editing these XML files. but, those files are also should be in Source Control. As of now, i am firing tf checkout method while saving XML from GUI tool. but, now, i need to implement the same when TFS server is offline too. Hope, this will gives you some more detail information.

Comment: @Jeeva S: In that case I see no other option but to do the process Visual Studio does (as described in my answer) manually or with support from some self-written tools.

Comment: thanks for ur help.. found the way.. used TFPT online command to do offline merge.. TFPT is from TFS power tools from VS Gallery. thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Jeeva S: Cool, I didn't know about that option. Thanks!